# Function list over a list of data frames without nesting apply()

Tags: r

With the data `dat` below, I'm trying to achieve the following result, only without nesting
 `lapply(, sapply...)`, like the following does.

```
> lapply(dat, function(x) sapply(funs, function(y) y(x)))
# $bondsba01
#   AVG   SLG 
# 0.223 0.300 
#
# $pujolal01
#   AVG   SLG 
# 0.329 0.422
```

I'm familiar with `rapply()`, but I'm having trouble implementing it over this list.  I figured since `dat` is a list of data frames, this call amounts to a list of lists, and `rapply` is appropriate.

I've tried a few variations of `rapply()`, and get the same error almost every time.

```
> rapply(funs, function(x) x(dat), how = "replace")
#  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'H' not found
```

I get the same error when `how = "list"` and `how =  "unlist"` How can I do this without nesting `sapply` with `lapply`?

**Sample Data:**

```
dat <- 
structure(list(bondsba01 = structure(list(AB = 413L, R = 72L, 
    H = 92L, X2B = 26L, X3B = 3L, HR = 16L, RBI = 48L, SB = 36L, 
    CS = 7L, BB = 65L, SO = 102L, IBB = 2L, HBP = 2L, SH = 2L, 
    SF = 2L), .Names = c("AB", "R", "H", "X2B", "X3B", "HR", 
"RBI", "SB", "CS", "BB", "SO", "IBB", "HBP", "SH", "SF"), row.names = 1L, 
    class = "data.frame"), 
    pujolal01 = structure(list(AB = 590L, R = 112L, H = 194L, 
        X2B = 47L, X3B = 4L, HR = 37L, RBI = 130L, SB = 1L, CS = 3L, 
        BB = 69L, SO = 93L, IBB = 6L, HBP = 9L, SH = 1L, SF = 7L), 
    .Names = c("AB", "R", "H", "X2B", "X3B", "HR", "RBI", "SB", "CS", "BB",
    "SO", "IBB", "HBP", "SH", "SF"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")),
    .Names = c("bondsba01", "pujolal01"))
```

**Function List:**

```
funs <- 
structure(list(AVG = function (x) 
with(x, round(H/AB, 3)), SLG = function (x) 
with(x, round(((H - X2B - X3B - HR) + 2 * X2B + 3 * X3B + HR)/AB, 
    3))), .Names = c("AVG", "SLG"))
```

[Link to the actual data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rmscriven/saber/master/data/batting.csv).

Comment: Perhaps consider `mapply`?

Comment: Perhaps this is not helpful for your actual data, but with (only) two functions in `funs` it seems you could also do `lapply(dat, function(x) c(funs$AVG(x), funs$SLG(x)))`

Comment: @beginneR , a nice idea, but the actual `funs` list has 6 functions in it.  And I'd also like to steer clear of the `$` operator for speed purposes.

Comment: Are all the list items the same length? If so, do you get a speed boost if you bind them together and use `apply`? You'll need to rewrite `funs` a little bit.

Comment: I think `mapply` gets close. `mapply("[[", dat, funs)` returns 
`Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'closure'`.  @AnandaMahto - If I do that I'd still need to split them again.  I'd like to return the list named the same as is began, but it could prove faster in the long run

Comment: @AnandaMahto - if by `length` you refer to column number, yes

Comment: I'm interested why you think `$` is slow?

Comment: Actually, I don't think you'll even need `apply`. Just haven't had a chance to load your example data and experiment yet :-)

Comment: If you don't need the list, you can get good speed binding and using `data.table`. Having to split again would take time though.

Comment: Your functions are vectorized so why not apply them to `do.call(rbind, dat)`? That vectorization will take care of the outer loop which is most likely the bottleneck. Just add an extra index column to your data so you'll be able to split it back when you are done. Now I realize that's what Ananda was also saying but I don't see why a data.table over a data.frame.

Comment: @flodel, I'm assuming that Richard must be working with something much larger if speed is a concern for him.

Comment: @flodel, although in that case, keeping it as a `matrix` makes the most sense....

Comment: @Ananda, functions like `round` are not faster when applied to a column of a data.table, are they? A `matrix` would make sense if his functions were applied to all values in a row, e.g. `rowSums` but it is not the case here. His functions only involve a few variables, and the ability to define them in a concise manner via `with` is a big plus. I doubt you win much (any?) speed using a matrix. And you constrain your data to one type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because it's Saturday morning, and I'm in the mood to experiment with `foreach`, here is a solution:

```
library(foreach)
library(iterators)

foreach(x=iter(dat), .combine=cbind) %:% 
  foreach(f=iter(funs), .combine=c)  %do% 
  f(x)


     result.1 result.2
[1,]    0.223    0.329
[2,]    0.300    0.422
```

This should be fast, but more importantly, it is pretty easy to parallelise foreach.  You only have to make two changes:

- Load your preferred parallel package (I use `doParallel`) and register the cluster
- Change `%do%` to `%dopar%`

Like this:

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
foreach(x=iter(dat), .combine=cbind) %:% 
  foreach(f=iter(funs), .combine=c)  %dopar% 
  f(x)

     result.1 result.2
[1,]    0.223    0.329
[2,]    0.300    0.422

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go.  [Here is why I think $ is slow](https://github.com/rmscriven/saber/blob/master/test/playerStats)

Comment: More specifically, it's `[.data.frame` that is slow.  Are they related?

Comment: @RichardScriven I believe so. I can't replicate your test, but try also `method3 <- function(ID){index <- which(ID == DATA$playerID); res <- DATA[index, -1]; rownames(res) <- NULL; res}` for a more direct comparison.